# apache(2.2.15) mod_jk configuration issue

Tags: apache, jboss, load-balancing, mod-jk

I have Two App Server running Jboss 7 and one Web Server

I have configured load balancing using mod_jk module

Below is my workers.properties

```
worker.list=loadbalancer,status,node1,node2

worker.node1.port=8009
worker.node1.host=ip1
worker.node1.type=ajp13
worker.node1.lbfactor=1

worker.node2.port=8009
worker.node2.host= ip2
worker.node2.type=ajp13
worker.node2.lbfactor=1

worker.loadbalancer.type=lb
worker.loadbalancer.balance_workers=node1,node2
worker.loadbalancer.sticky_session=0
worker.list=loadbalancer

worker.status.type=status
```

Below is my uriworkermap.properties

```
/jmx-console=loadbalancer
/jmx-console/*=loadbalancer
/web-console=loadbalancer
/web-console/*=loadbalancer
/App/*=loadbalancer
```

Below entries I did in my httpd.conf file

```
<Proxy balancer://App>
BalancerMember ajp://xx.xx.xx.1:8009/App route=node1  
BalancerMember ajp://xx.xx.xx.2:8009/App route=node2  
ProxySet stickysession=JSESSIONID                         
</Proxy>                                                  

ProxyPass /App balancer://App                       
ProxyPassReverse /App balancer://App                
<Location /balancer-manager>                              
SetHandler balancer-manager                               
</Location>
```

Below is the mod-jk.conf file

```
LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so
JkWorkersFile conf/workers.properties
JkLogFile logs/mod_jk.log                                       
JkLogLevel info                                                 
JkLogStampFormat  "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y]"                      
JkOptions +ForwardKeySize +ForwardURICompat -ForwardDirectories 
JkRequestLogFormat "%w %V %T"                                   
JkMount /App/* loadbalancer                                  
JkMountFile conf/uriworkermap.properties                        
JkShmFile logs/jk.shm                                           
<Location /jkstatus>                                            
    JkMount status                                          
    Order deny,allow                                        
    Deny from all                                           
    Allow from 127.0.0.1                                    
</Location>
```

There is some issue in the session which i dont understand how to do it.

whenever i m starting apache httpd and hitting Web Server URL the application login page opens up properly with proper load balancing on both the app server.

Scenario 1: When i hit http://xx.xx.xx.xx/App/ it goes to App Server 1. but when i enter username/password and clink on login button it goes to app server 2 instead of going to app server 1.

Comment: guys any suggestions plz?

Comment: I suggest you try superuser.com or serverfault.com, you're off topic here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using standalone JBoss Server add the instance-id as follows for each instance in your standalone.xml and session affinity will start working.

For node1,

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" default-virtual-server="default-host" instance-id="node1" native="false">
```

For node2,

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" default-virtual-server="default-host" instance-id="node2" native="false">
```

Below are some links which may help you (both for standalone.xml and server.xml),

[Link1](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/201760?tstart=0)

[Link2](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/clustering-http-jboss.html)